# e ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes

Tags: jersey, tomcat7, jax-rs

I understand this has been answered in many posts, but I am unable to find correct solution.

I am not giving @Path at class level but at method level (as it extends my URI) due to this I get ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes. exception on deployment

```
public class PatientResource {
@GET
@Path("/patient/{patientId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Patient getPatientDetails(@PathParam("patientId") String patientId) {
      ...
    }
```

Web xml entry is

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.clinic.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
```

So when I try serv-name:8080/WAR-Id/rest/patient/1 I get above exception. Note that I can get rid of exception if I add @Path at class level, but it unnecessarily extends URL, Also giving /* in web xml is not feasible for project. Bottomline - IS it necessary to give @Path at class level

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have a `Patient` resource you would normally place a

```
@Path("/patient")
```

on the class and then a

```
@Path("{patientId}")
```

on the method.

Comment: This is a good approach. However I have few other methods like getAllPatients, in that case having a uri like "patient/all" doesn't look good.

Comment: The traditional RESTful way of obtaining all patients is to use the URL /patient (and to be totally traditional you would usually use the plural for the root resource, so to obtain all patients use /patients, to access  patient 3 use /patients/3).  If you do this then your class has a `@Path("/patients")` annotation, your `getAll()` has no path annotation, and your `getPatient()` has a `@Path("{patientId}")` annotation.